# Sharing a Display Remotely Over a Managed Network

Tags: hdmi, remote-access, remote, microsoft-teams, screen-sharing

We have a computer running at a remote site with the OS being RedHat Linux. We'd like to share the display remotely, back to our main site so engineers there can observe from one or more displays.

The remote site computer is a product with a managed configuration, but it is not and cannot be placed directly on the main company network. Making software changes on this computer to support this screen sharing objective should be kept to a minimum. I'm thinking I'd like that computer to just treat this as a duplicate screen connected over HDMI, but I'm open to other suggestions. USB-C connections are supported, if that helps.

I'll need a gateway device to bridge the duplicated display output to a computer that's on the company's managed network. This could be a Windows computer that is co-located at the remote site and can be on the company network. It can be manually set up to screen share by somebody who is at that remote site, if that's necessary.

Ideally, it would be helpful if the remote display can be shared to multiple computers. Using Teams running on the bridge computer with a shared desktop might be one way. I only suggest this as an idea, and I have no idea if it makes sense. (Teams would have to "see" the shared screen in order to put it out to the main site viewers/users.)

How would I go about this? What I describe above is a set of constraints and a conceptual solution, but I have no idea what would be the most practical way to do it.